# Run node module in browser

Tags: javascript, node.js, npm, node-modules, httpserver

I'm trying to upload and read excel file using this node module: [read-excel-file](https://www.npmjs.com/package/read-excel-file) and according to the instructions under **Browser** I need to put this code in my .js file:

```
import readXlsxFile from 'read-excel-file'

const input = document.getElementById('input')

input.addEventListener('change', () => {
  readXlsxFile(input.files[0]).then((rows) => {
    // `rows` is an array of rows
    // each row being an array of cells.
  })
})
```

But the browser doesn't know what is `import readXlsxFile from 'read-excel-file'`. It should be noted that I'm using `http-server` to see my project at `http://localhost:8080/`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

TL;DR: You have to actually compile your JS code into browser-usable code. Use [webpack](https://webpack.js.org/) or [other bundling tools](https://survivejs.com/webpack/appendices/comparison/#bundlers) to do so.

Long story: The browser does not understand `import` (because for example: where is the resource?). You can use tools like webpack to create bundles of JavaScript code that detect on compile time that import XX from YY means that they have to look in de node_modules or bower_modules folder for that module and include it in the final bundle

PS: Be aware that not all npm modules are able to run in the browser since thy are node modules or vice versa (they provide different APIs).

Comment: Browsers do have [native support for modules](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Guide/Modules) now, but modules designed for Node.js (with Node.js' module resolution system) won't be supported.

Answer (score -1):

A different library might be the answer. One the works in the browser is [sheetjs](https://sheetjs.com/).

Theres a working demo here: https://sheetjs.com/demos/modify.html